# Java Script is not executing in magento

Tags: javascript, magento

We have developed a custom payment gateway.
where user can select an emi option to pay.In Model I have declared

```
protected $_formBlockType = 'mygateway/form'
```

And in Block I have declared

```
 protected function _construct()
{
    parent::_construct();

    $this->setTemplate('mygateway/form.phtml');
}
```

My form.phtml will look like

```
 <label style="margin-left:190px;background-color:#999;font-size:16px;font-weight:300px;">Select EMI Option : </label>     
 <select id="bankInfo" style="margin-left:10px;margin-top:50px;" onchange="getEMIDetail()">
```

Select Bank

But getEMIDetail is not getting Called.

Please Advice

Comment: Make sure that include js file with function getEMIDetail().

Comment: i have written java script in same page only that is form.phtml

Comment: Are you getting any JavaScript errors in the browser console? If you are, please include them here. If you are not, replace the getEMIDetail() with alert("hasChanged") to check the event is working. Remember if the user selects the incumbent value the browser will not fire onchange because there was not a change.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Malachy,now i am able to call java script.In select I am adding values dynamically,it is also working fine but after addition,select option is getting disabled and I have no where written disable option in code.